# How to ask for input, store and then display afterwards?

Tags: assembly, io, keyboard, x86, dos

I have been working on this for days but I just don't get how assembly works.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

**"Please press two keys on the keyboard: op


You pressed o and p"**

Here's what I have so far, and I can't figure out what's wrong or missing:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 0
.DATA
    msg db 0ah, 0dh, "Please press two keys: $"
    s1 db 0ah, 0dh, "You pressed $"
    s2 db 0ah, 0dh, " and $"

    char1 db ?
    char2 db ?


.CODE
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds,ax

    mov dx, offset msg

    mov ah,9
    int 21h



    mov ah,1
    int 21h
    mov char1, al
    int 21h

    mov char2, al
    int 21h


    mov ah,2
    mov dl, char1
    int 21h
    mov dl, char2
    int 21h

    lea dx, s1
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h



    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

END
```

It only allows me to press 2 keys, then it terminates.

Forgive my code, honestly I don't have much of an idea what I'm doing, my instructor never went into details about this.

Comment: You have an extra `int 21h` after reading the second character. Also, you are echoing the characters before you have printed the message.

Comment: I am not familiar with dos assembly, but in Linux using the interrupts in this order, should work: write "Please press two keys on the keyboard: " // read 1 byte // write "You pressed " // write 1 byte // write " and " // read 1 byte // write 1 byte // In this case you need to reserve a single 1 byte buffer in .bss. But I think, it is different in DOS.

Comment: @Jester what do you suggest I do?

Comment: What I said - remove the extra int 21h and put the message printing before printing the characters.

Comment: @Jester i'm sorry i cant figure out which part you are pointing to, honestly im just following a pattern